Compare groups in Sphinx
This example not working in Sphinx with HAVING. I get syntax error.
Please explain me, how can I compare groups correctly?
SELECT someId from rt_index
GROUP BY someId 
HAVING MIN(someId) != MAX(someId)


In general you would put the 'expression' into the select clause, then can use it in having.
SELECT someId,MAX(otherId)-MIN(otherId) AS range FROM rt_index
GROUP BY someId 
HAVING range != 0

I changed it to use MAX(otherId), because grouping by someId;  MIN(someId) would ALWAYS match MAX(someId)
